# Telerik MVC Grid - How to add a new record?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a Telerik Kendo Grid and I am adding a record when I click a button:

```
var dataSource = $("#GridArticulos").data("kendoGrid").dataSource; 
dataSource.add({ ArticuloId: articuloId, Nombre: nombre, Precio:
precio, Cantidad: cantidad, Total: total }); 
dataSource.sync();
```

The record is added correctly to the grid, but when I click the save button on the grid, nothing happens, the action in the controller is not called, do I need some specific configuration on the grid?, this is what I have now:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<App.Models.ArticulosListaViewModel>()
                    .Name("GridArticulos")
                    .AutoBind(false)
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(c => c.ArticuloId).Width("15%");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Nombre).Width("35%").ClientFooterTemplate("Total"); ;
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Cantidad).Width("10%").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" });
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Precio).Width("10%").Format("{0:C}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" });
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Total).Width("10%").Format("{0:C}").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align:right" })
                            .ClientFooterTemplate("<div align=\"right\">#=kendo.format('{0:C}', sum)#</div>");
                        columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width("20%");
                    })
                    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                    {
                        toolbar.Save().SaveText("Crear pedido").CancelText("Cancelar");
                    })                       
                    .Selectable(s => s.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single).Type(GridSelectionType.Cell))
                    .Scrollable()
                    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px", @class = "ra-section" })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .Aggregates(aggregates => 
                        {
                            aggregates.Add(p => p.Total).Sum();
                        })
                        .Batch(true)
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                        .Events(events => events.Error("GridArticulos_Error").RequestEnd("GridArticulos_RequestEnd"))
                        .Model(model =>
                        {
                            model.Id(a => a.ArticuloId);
                            model.Field(a => a.Nombre).Editable(false);
                            model.Field(a => a.Cantidad).Editable(false);
                            model.Field(a => a.Precio).Editable(false);
                            model.Field(a => a.Total).Editable(false);
                        })                           
                        //.Create(create => create.Action("GuardarPedido", "Pedidos").Data("ObtenerDatos"))
                        .Update(update => update.Action("GuardarPedido", "Pedidos").Data("ObtenerDatos"))
                        .Destroy(d => d.Action("EliminarArticulo", "Pedidos"))
                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

you have your .Create() method commented out.  uncomment it and point it to the appropriate controller method and you should be fine

uncomment this line-->  //.Create(create => create.Action("GuardarPedido", "Pedidos").Data("ObtenerDatos"))
                        .Update(update => update.Action("GuardarPedido", "Pedidos").Data("ObtenerDatos"))
                        .Destroy(d => d.Action("EliminarArticulo", "Pedidos"))

also, your create method is pointed to the same method as your update method on the line below it so you would need to edit the method to point to another method.  I can't help there since I don't know what methods you have in your controller